# Search and print matching string

Tags: shell

have a folder structure as shown below
./all_files

`-rwxrwxrwx  reference_file.txt`
`drwxrwxrwx  file1.txt`
`drwxrwxrwx  file2.txt`
`drwxrwxrwx  file3.txt`

reference_file.txt has filenames as shown below

`file1.txt`
`file2.txt`

data in file1.txt and file2.txt are as shown below:

step_1
step_2
step_3

Now, I have to take particular step say step2 from each file

Note1: file name must present in reference_file.txt

Note2: step2 is not line no:2 always.

Note3: search should perform recursively.

I have used below scripts:

1. which is not giving what i expected. All blank and unwanted lines displayed

`#!/bin/sh`

`while read f; do`
   `find . -type f -name "${f}" | xargs  grep -l -F 'step_2'`
`done <reference_file.txt`

2. It is searching in only one folder but not searching recursively

`#!/bin/sh`

`for i in reference_file.txt`
do
find . -type f -name "${f}" | xargs  grep -l -F 'step_2'
done

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

With removing -l option it works for me.

`for f in`cat reference_file.txt`; do find . -type f -name $f | xargs grep 'step_2' ; done`

I can see it works recursively as well. See the output below when I run it from outside of `dir1` (directory structure created by me)

`./dir1/file1:step_2:

./dir1/file2:step_2:`

Please share more information like directory structure and file names if issue in recursion still exists.

Comment: thank you... i noticed the ; at the end of for loop line which i missed... also i made changes to find statement instead od name $f i used    wild card *.txt... because $f is throwing error `find: incomplete statement`

Comment: here is the code used `#!/bin/sh`

`for i in cat reference_file.txt;`

`do`
`find . -type f -name *.txt | xargs  grep -F 'step_2'`
`done<reference_file.txt``... but i am getting the ouput twice.

Comment: If you are searching for `*.txt` then remove the for loop.  Just try `find . -type f -name *.txt | xargs grep -F 'step_2'`. But this will not search for files only written in reference_file.txt.

Comment: if i use the same code i got the error message.. said earlier... `# bash -x script.sh`
`+ for i in cat reference_file.txt`
`+ find . -type f -name **cat**`
`+ xargs grep -F 'step_2'`
`+ for i in cat **reference_file.txt**`
`+ find . -type f -name reference_file.txt`
`+ xargs grep -F 'step_2'`   .... no output at all, please check