# Search using reference file and print matching lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix

have a folder structure as shown below ./all_files

```
-rwxrwxrwx  reference_file.txt
drwxrwxrwx  file1.txt
drwxrwxrwx  file2.txt
drwxrwxrwx  file3.txt
```

reference_file.txt has filenames as shown below

```
$cat reference_file.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

data in file1.txt and file2.txt are as shown below:

```
$cat file1.txt
step_1
step_2
step_3
```

Now, I have to take particular step say step2 from each file

Note1: file name must present in reference_file.txt

Note2: step2 is not line no:2 always.

Note3: search should perform recursively.

I have used below script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in cat reference_file.txt;

do
   find . -type f -name $i | grep -v 'FS*' | xargs  grep -F 'step_2'
done<reference_file.txt
```

after using above code i got no output.

```
# bash -x script.sh
+ for i in cat reference_file.txt
+ find . -type f -name **cat**
+ xargs grep -F 'step_2'
+ for i in cat **reference_file.txt**
+ find . -type f -name reference_file.txt
+ xargs grep -F 'step_2'
```

Added New requirement:

target=step_XX_2 where XX can be anything and should be skipped for search.. so that desire ouput will be.. step_ab_2 step_cd_2 step_ef_2

Comment: Why are you reading `reference_file.txt` twice?  You `cat` the file and you also redirect it into the standard input of the loop - which it appears you don't use.  What are you trying to achieve using two asterisks?

Comment: Could you please show the desired output?

Comment: Your for loop iterates over two elements, `cat` and `reference_file.txt`. Use `while read` instead of `for`.

Comment: I think, you were trying to do `for i in $(cat reference_file.txt);` & not `for i in cat reference_file.txt;` Using `while read` loop is better option.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `FS*`?  In regular expressions that means "F followed by zero or more S's".  Not the same as a wildcard (globbing).

Comment: the asterisks kept to highlight(bold) text.. but not part of code.. someone give me code using while loop please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.  Please let me know:

EDIT:  my previous version did not search recursively.
Further edits:  Note that using process substitution for `find` means that this script MUST be run under `bash` and not `sh`.

Further edit for change in specification:  note the change to `target` and the `-E` option to `grep` instead of `-F`.

```
#!/bin/bash

target='step_.*?_?2'

while read -r name
do
   # EDIT: exclude certain directories
   if [[ $name == "old1" || $name == "old2" ]]
   then
        # do the next iteration of the loop
        continue    
   fi

   while read -r fname
   do
       if [[ $fname != FS* ]]
       then
           # Display the filename (grep -H is not in POSIX)
           if out=$(grep -E "$target" "$fname")
           then
               echo "$fname: $out"
           fi
       fi
   done < <(find . -type f -name "$name")

done < reference_file.txt
```

Note that your trace (`bash -x`) uses bash but your `#!` line uses `sh`.  They are different - you should be consistent with the shell you are using.

So, I have dropped the `xargs`, that reads strings standard input and executes a program using the strings as argument.  Since we already have the argument strings for `grep` we don't need it.

Your `grep -v 'FS*'` probably doesn't do what you expect.  The regular expression `FS*` means "F followed by zero or more S's". Not the same as a shell pattern matching (globbing).  In my solution I have used `FS*` because I am using the shell, not `grep`.

Comment: thank you, is it possible to display the filename as well... `file1.txt: step_2` `file2.txt: step_2` so that i can check if the file is also present in reference_file.txt

Comment: Nice! See a good comparison on [How to loop through file names returned by find?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/1983854), since `for fname in $(find ...)` doesn't seem very safe.

Comment: @fedorqui could please suggest the changes in code, which uses only while loop please. also the display includes both files name and result

Comment: Suggested changes adopted.  Please note that using process substitution for `find` means that this script MUST be run under `bash` and not `sh`.

Comment: @cdarke the output also showing the all remaining lines in reference_file.txt... 
`file1.txt: step2`
`file2.txt: step2`
`file3.txt: file4.txt: file5.txt` and so on

Comment: I misunderstood the data.  Code amended.

Comment: @cdarke please find below details:
`step_2 may not be available in every file`
`most important point was the file name must exists in reference_file.txt, if present it should go for next search(step_2)`
`then search for step_2, if present then display filename: step_2`

please help

Comment: Like I said, I misunderstood.  Yes, I see it now.  Did you try my new solution?

Comment: @cdarke missed your last update.. thank you.. new code is working fine

Comment: @cdarke shall i have one more update
`target=step_XX_2`
where XX can be anything and should be skipped for search..
so that desire ouput will be..
`step_ab_2`
`step_cd_2`
`step_ef_2`

Comment: Can you update the main question with that please?  I'll post another comment when done.

Comment: Can't do that if you insist on using the `-F` option to `grep`, since it needs a regular expression.  Please get back to me on that.

Comment: Change done, not that `target` has changes, and now I use `-E` in `grep`.

Comment: @cdarke i tried with the new code but seems the target is not working fine..
`The exact target string was 01.XX.20XX` 
i am searching the date format with XX can be anything..
please suggest

Comment: That's different to what you specified before.  Your said "`target=step_XX_2`" - underscore, not dot.   You need to construct a regular expression for the pattern you want.  You really should at least give me a full specification of the pattern you want to match.  Is that *exactly* two characters when you say "XX"?

Comment: @cdarke yes... exactly 2 characters.. the one i specified last is the exact string i am searching for

Comment: So your target pattern is `'01\...\.20..`.  The `\.` means a literal dot, otherwise `.` means one single character.

Comment: @cdarke thank you its works perfect..
i am trying to add one more condition in if condition and i tried below combinations and didn't work
`if [[ $fname != FS*  && old*]]`
`if [[ $fname != "FS*"  && "old*"]]`
`if [[ $fname != (FS*  && old*)]]`
`if [[ $fname != ("FS*"  && "old*")]]`

Comment: got it. added space at the end `if [[ $fname != FS* && old* ]]`

Comment: @cdarke is it possible to exclude specific directories in find command?
`ex: (find .! (old1, old2) -type f -name "$name")`
that means dont look in old1,old2 directories while searching

Comment: Just put an `if` statement between the two `while` loops.  I'll modify the code to show that.  You really should try some of this yourself!

Comment: @cdarke tried below things and not getting desired output

`if [[ $name == "old1" || $name == "old2" ]]`
`if [[ $name != "old1" || $name != "old2" ]]`

first statement also searching in the directories  old1, old2
second statement exiting the loop there itself.

Comment: If you use `!=` then you need `&&` not `||`.

Comment: @cdarke even that also failed, even if one arguement

`if [[ $name != "old1" && "OLD2" ]]`
`if [[ $name != "old1" ]]`

`+ read -r name`
`+ [[ file1.txt != \o\l\d\1 ]]`
`+ [[ -n OLD2 ]]`
`+ continue`

`+ read -r name`
`+ [[ file1.txt != \o\l\d\1 ]]`
`+ continue`

Comment: `[[ $name != "old1" && "OLD2" ]]` is wrong, should be `[[ $name != "old1" && $name != "OLD2" ]]`.   I can't figure out what your code is from the comment (what are all thous `+`s).  Please post and format your code in the question.

Comment: @cdarke the + sign is when i execute the script using -x `ex: bash -x script.sh` to debug the script.
here i observed the folder name searching as `[[ file1.txt != \o\l\d\1 ]]`.

also in my last comment even if i pass single folder name as argument [[ $name != "old1" ]], i didn't get the output.

please tell me if i missed any detail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609731/search-and-print-matching-string/38611843?noredirect=1#comment64763865_38611843)

What you need is

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `cat reference_file.txt`
    do  find . -type f -name $i | grep -v 'FS*' | xargs  grep -F 'step_2'  
done
```

See the backticks and Do Not read the file reference_file.txt twice.

Comment: `$(cat reference_file.txt)` syntax is preferred, backticks are considered deprecated.  Better yet, you rarely need `cat`.

Comment: @cdarke a `for i in $(cat ...)` is not safe. [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). It is best to say `while IFS= read -r var1 var2 ... ; do ... done < file`.

Comment: @fedorqui:  No argument with that see my post.  `cat` is rarely needed in a script.  The point of my comment was about backticks.